# Ordered comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

```
- (void) dealloc
{
[_id_list release];
[super dealloc];
}

- (void)update {
CFArrayRef ar = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
CFDictionaryRef window;
CFIndex i;
CGWindowID wid;

[_id_list release];
_id_list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (i=0; i < window =" CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(ar," name =" (NSString*)CFDictionaryGetValue(window," owner_name =" (NSString*)CFDictionaryGetValue(window,");}
```

for the last line, Xcode gives error:

- 'Semantic Issue: Ordered comparison between pointer and integer ('CFIndex' (aka 'long') and 'CFDictionaryRef' (aka 'const struct __CFDictionary *'))'

And, specifically for this it warns:

- i < window
- 'Expression is not assignable'

Basically, I'm trying to get WindowID of Desktop (wallpaper only).
Why does this happen?

Comment: It's meaningless to compare an int (or any other "scalar") to a pointer.  Any CFxxxRef value is a pointer.

Comment: Further, `window =" CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(ar,"` makes no sense -- you're attempting to assign a char string to an CFDictionaryRef.  (Or did you somehow garble the source when you pasted it?)

Comment: okay - I must admit that I copied it from a blog explaining how to get unique CGWindowID. From here (translated via Google): http://bit.ly/nfY4VX To get Desktop wallpaper's unique ID I knew it was something to do with `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`, but other than that I had no idea...

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
for (i=0; i < window =" CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(ar," name =" (NSString*)CFDictionaryGetValue(window," owner_name =" (NSString*)CFDictionaryGetValue(window,");}
```

Doesn't make any sense.  for loops are generally:

```
for ( assignment-expr; comparison-expr ; increment-expr )
{
    body-of-for-loop
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the fact that there is some crazy stuff going on in that for loop, the compiler is complaining because:

```
CFDictionaryRef window;
CFIndex i;
```

And this part:

```
i < window
```

It makes no sense to compare an index (long) to a dictionary.